# Stuck on complexity analysis of a tricky program

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics

Really stuck the complexity analysis of this problem .
Given digits 0–9 , we need to find all the numbers of max length k whose digits will be in increasing order .

```
for example if k = 3 , numbers can be 0,00,000,01,02,03,04,.... 1,11,111,12,...
```

So the question basically that if repetitions allowed for digits,
How many such combinations are possible to find all the numbers less than `size k (less than digit length k)` such that digits from left to right will be non-decreasing order.

Comment: Well, great, let us know when you're done...

Comment: So do you want to find the *number* of combinations or list the combinations themselves?

Comment: It's choose(k+10, 10) - 1, using stars and bars. That takes O(1) arithmetic operations to compute.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog , i want to find number of such combinations .

Comment: Why my question has 2 down vote ?  Whats wrong in it ?

Comment: @AjitKumar [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Thanks will take care from next time ..:)

Answer (score 2):

Numbers with at most `k` digits that are weakly increasing are in 1-1 correspondence with binary strings of length `k+10`, with exactly ten 1's. The number of consecutive `0`s just before the `i`th one and one in the binary string is the number of `i` digits in the original number. For example, if `k=7`, then `001119` maps to `00100011111111010` (2 zeros, 3 ones, 0 twos, 0 threes, ..., 0 eights, 1 nine, 1 digit left over to make the number of digits up to 7).

These binary strings are easy to count: there's `choose(k+10, 10)-1` of them (missing one because the empty number is disallowed). This can be computed in O(1) arithmetic operations (actually 10 additions, 18 multiplications and one division).

Comment: Thanks @Paul , I can't understand the first sentence "Numbers with at most k digits that are weakly increasing are in 1-1 correspondence with binary strings of length k+10, with exactly ten 1's." 
Sorry i am little weak in math .

Comment: Understood now , Thanks every one . I just went through bars and stars theorem 2 and understood the logic . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Thanks again Paul .

Comment: Since i have low reputation , i cant vote it . Please if somebody has higher reputation up vote this post .

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation neither, so I cannot answer Paul's or Globe's answer.

Globe's answer choose(k+9,9) is not perfect, because it only counts the solutions where the numbers have **exactly** k digits. But the original problems allows numbers with less digits too.

Paul's answer choose(k+10,10) counts these shorter numbers too, but it also allows numbers with zero digits. Let's say k=7 then the following binary string describes a number with no digits: 11111111110000000. We have to exclude this one.

So the solution is: choose(k+10,10)-1

Comment: Thanks for the answer .